# Plotly's add_hline() function is not drawing the mean line on the plot

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, customization

I recently started working with plotly and it was good. It went great until now. Right now, I am trying to add a horizontal line on my plot by using the mean of `'balance'` column from the dataframe. But when I am trying to add it, it is drawing it on zero. So I tried doing it separately outside of `add_hline()` function and it seems to be working perfectly.

Here is the code:

```
ed_s = px.histogram(
       data_frame=df,
       x = 'age',
       y = 'balance',
       color='y',
       labels={'age':"Age", "balance":"Balance"},
       title=format_title("Age and Balance", "Also whether the customer subed to a term deposit or not"),
template=custom_template)

fig = go.Figure(data=ed_s)
fig.add_hline(y=mean_balance, line_dash='dash', line_color="firebrick")
iplot(fig)
```

[image]

As you can see the line is drawn at 0. I will also link the [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/kukuroo3/bank-marketing-response-predict).

Comment: How are you calculating `mean_balance`. If you are taking mean of `balance` column, it is `1483`, so the line is probably correct

Comment: Yes, that is what I did. But is it correct? @Redox